# ways to add text to an image

Tags: c#, c++, windows, image, text

In my C++ program, I want to be able to add some text over an image.  I can already load/save the image, I just need to add text to it.

I want to be able to use different fonts, colors, italics, bold, solid/transparent background, have a border around the letters, etc.

I've done this in the past by using the old MFC functions to generate black text over white background, and doing my own processing to add the other effects.

1-Is there an easier way to generate the black text on white background?  Using a DLL created from C# or .net would be fine.

2-Is there something which can directly do all I want to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDI+ is what you are looking for.

In .NET you will find the GDI+ classes in System.Drawing (requires assembly reference to System.Drawing.dll).

Especially the class Graphics and its method Graphics.FromImage will help you.

Comment: The C++ interface is almost identical, so .NET isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: @Turnor: I understood that he wants to do it in .NET: "Using a DLL created from C# or .net would be fine."

Answer (score 3):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/?ImageMagick=9n7k105r5vah1ai16tvjtustl2) has a C++ api that you can use to access its image processing functionality. ImageMagick has a *ton* of functionality, I would look into it for all your image processing needs.

Comment: Can Imagemagick create 32-bit text with alpha channel in memory, so I can my compositing separately?

Comment: You should be able to - you may have some translation to do between sucking out the pixel values from ImageMagick's instances to whatever format you want, but ImageMagick provides objects all the way down to the pixel level - see http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Pixels.html